# Contact Manager App Crashing

Tags: android, android-fragments, contacts, pager

Yeah so basically I set out to make an android app that saves and displays contacts on the phone using SQLite and everything. I am a total newbie at this and have had no formal training in Android Application Developemnt. The contact manager app is a part of a bigger app idea that has been brewing in my mind. The basic thing that I want to create first is a feature to save contacts and view them in same fragment activity using the side-scrolling pager. The thing is, the pager worked fine until I put some code to save and display contacts in the FragmentActivities. When I used test Fragment Activities, everything worked fine and smoothly. Please have a look at the Following code try to tell me what's wring with my code. Also, I am using an actual phone to run the apps (Nokia X), so tell me if that could be a factor too?

```
package com.example.nikhil.test1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
* Created by nikhil on 22-10-2015.
 */
public class ContactEdit extends Fragment {
MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this.getActivity());
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_contact_edit, container, false);


    Button SaveBTN = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BtnSave);
    SaveBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText _Name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textName);
            EditText _Mobile = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textMobile);
            EditText _Home = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textHome);
            EditText _Address = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textAddress);

            String name = _Name.getText().toString();
            String mobile = _Mobile.getText().toString();
            String home = _Home.getText().toString();
            String address = _Address.getText().toString();

            databaseHelper.addFriend(name, address, mobile, home);

        }
    });

    return rootView;

    }

}
    package com.example.nikhil.test1;
    import android.app.LoaderManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri; 
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks; 
    import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
    import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

    public class ContactList extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private LoaderManager supportLoaderManager;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.contact_row, container, false);
        MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this.getActivity());

        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllFriends();
        String [] from = new String[] {"name","phonenumber"};
        int[] to = { R.id.name, R.id.phonenumber};
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to);
        ListView myList=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Uri uri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(this.getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        adapter.swapCursor(arg1);
    }
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}


import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;


public class Contacts extends ContentProvider {
    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.nikhil.test1.Contacts";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/contacts" );
    private static final int Contacts = 1;
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "contacts", Contacts);
    }
    MyDatabaseHelper mMyDataBaseHelper;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mMyDataBaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==Contacts){
            return (Uri) mMyDataBaseHelper.getAllFriends();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have only given the relevant codes. Also here is my Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nikhil.test1" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstSplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_splash_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.nikhil.test1.FirstSplashScreen" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:authorities="com.example.nikhil.test1.Contacts"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```